# How to calculate percentages with GROUP BY query over many different variables?

Tags: sql, group-by, databricks

I have a source table containing many character columns and another final numeric column (named ASSISTANCE). Just for completeness, let's say there are about 30 character columns.

Here is an example of the source table. The final numeric variable **ASSISTANCE**, that each character variable is to split into is found at the last column:

| AGE_GROUP | GENDER_TYP | Employment_flag | Indigenous_flag | Remoteness | ASSISTANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 to 7 | Male | Yes | No | Very remote | 1 |
| 8 to 12 | Female | Yes | No | Metro | 2 |
| 0 to 7 | Female | No | No | Metro | 2 |
| 13 to 18 | Not stated | No | No | Rural | 3 |
| 13 to 18 | Not stated | No | No | Remote | 3 |

(Note, I refer to **Question_response** below, as a placeholder for any of those above variables)

For each of those character columns (say, the character column **Question_response**, taking on values **YES**, **NO**, **UNKNOWN**), I would like to get the percentage within each of those values, split by the numeric **ASSISTANCE** (ranging from 1 to 3) variable.
The numerator would be the count of respondents who responded within each subgroup of the **Question_response** variable and the **ASSISTANCE** variable, and the denominator is the count of respondents within each subgroup of only the **Question_response** variable.

So here is what an example would look like:

| Question_response | ASSISTANCE | count | char_pct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| YES | 1 | 10 | 0.2222 |
| YES | 2 | 20 | 0.4444 |
| YES | 3 | 15 | 0.3333 |
| NO | 1 | 2 | 0.1666 |
| NO | 2 | 4 | 0.3333 |
| NO | 3 | 6 | 0.5 |
| UNKNOWN | 1 | 2 | 0.2 |
| UNKNOWN | 2 | 3 | 0.3 |
| UNKNOWN | 3 | 5 | 0.5 |

Now, there are a lot of these character variables, similar to **Question_Response**. How would I go about doing this in a fast automated way for all of the character variables, without copy pasting code and changing 1 variable each time? Below is the code I found for just 1 variable.

Here is the code for just 1 iteration of one of the character variables.

```
select split.Question_response as Question_response
,split.ASSISTANCE as ASSISTANCE
,split.count as count
,(100.0 * split.count)/total.count as char_pct
from
(select Question_response, ASSISTANCE, count(*) as count
from source_table
group by Question_response, ASSISTANCE
) as split
join
(select Question_response, count(*) as count
from source-table
group by Question_response
) as total
on total.Question_response = split.Question_response
order by Question_response, ASSISTANCE
```

An alternative piece of code for the above is:

```
select Question_response
,ASSISTANCE
,count(*) as count
,100.0 * count(*)/sum(count(*)) over (partition by Question_response) as char_pct
from source_table
group by Question_response, ASSISTANCE
order by Question_response, ASSISTANCE
```

I understand the logic here, but I would like a final table containing this split by ALL character variables.

This final table would look something like this. It stacks up all the tables that have been produced:

| Variable | Variable_value | ASSISTANCE | count | char_pct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Question_response | YES | 1 | 10 | 0.2222 |
| Question_response | YES | 2 | 20 | 0.4444 |
| Question_response | YES | 3 | 15 | 0.3333 |
| Question_response | NO | 1 | 2 | 0.1666 |
| Question_response | NO | 2 | 4 | 0.3333 |
| Question_response | NO | 3 | 6 | 0.5 |
| Question_response | UNKNOWN | 1 | 2 | 0.2 |
| Question_response | UNKNOWN | 2 | 3 | 0.3 |
| Question_response | UNKNOWN | 3 | 5 | 0.5 |
| Language_spoken | ENGLISH | 1 | 10 | 0.2222 |
| Language_spoken | ENGLISH | 2 | 20 | 0.4444 |
| Language_spoken | ENGLISH | 3 | 15 | 0.3333 |
| Language_spoken | NON_ENGLISH | 1 | 2 | 0.1666 |
| Language_spoken | NON_ENGLISH | 2 | 4 | 0.3333 |
| Language_spoken | NON_ENGLISH | 3 | 6 | 0.5 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Where Language_spoken is another character variable from source_table.
For more clarity, the first **char_pct** calculation is done by 10/(10+20+15) = 0.2222

Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: You can write a program to write the query for you. This would be made easier by using a SQL query builder in the language of your choice. For example, [Knex.js](https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html).

Comment: What database are you using? Some databases have filters on aggregation functions (like count) which can make this much easier.

Comment: @Schwern I'll be honest, I'm completely new to SQL so I don't quite know. I'm using SQL inside Databricks. Is Databricks the database?

Comment: I don't know about Databricks. I've tagged the question.

Comment: You can get part of the way there using [grouping sets](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-groupby.html), but I don't know how to easily incorporate the total. [Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/1oYKMJFj).

Comment: @Schwern I've just added in an alternate code for one iteration - tagged you in case it fits with your demonstration.

Comment: What I would dearly like to see is a sample of the source_table. It doesn't need 30 char columns, but it does need to show "*a lot of these character variables, similar to Question_Response*" we don't need the whole enchilada, but enough to visualize what you are dealing with.

Comment: **also:** Is the table one specific survey or test? Do the names of columns refer to a specific question? please include some representative column names in your sample data and what the column names refer to.

Comment: @AdrianMaxwell I've just added a sample of what the source table would look like. The source table is pretty much a table of respondents to a survey, but the survey asks about demographic information e.g. their age group,  gender type, whether or not they're employed, their area of remoteness.   
Sorry for using "Question_response" - it was supposed to be a placeholder for any of those variables. There isn't any discernible pattern to the column naming convention unfortunately.

Comment: It's quite possible that the demonstration by @Schwern using grouping sets may be the better approach than what I have proposed below. I think you should consider both approaches for suitability and performance.

Comment: A better design might be a many-to-1 relationship. 1 survey row (id, assistance, any additional info about the survey) has many rows in a question and answer table (question, answer, survey id).

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion is **untested**, but I suggest transforming your source data first (in databricks) like so:

```
SELECT
  AGE_GROUP,
  map_entries(map('GENDER_TYP', GENDER_TYP, 'Employment_flag', Employment_flag, 'Indigenous_flag', Indigenous_flag, 'Remoteness', Remoteness, 'ASSISTANCE', ASSISTANCE)) as key_value_pairs
FROM
  source_table
```

This will place the core information into JSON like this

```
AGE_GROUP   key_value_pairs
0 to 7  [{GENDER_TYP: Male, Employment_flag: Yes, Indigenous_flag: No, Remoteness: Very remote, ASSISTANCE: 1}]
8 to 12 [{GENDER_TYP: Female, Employment_flag: Yes, Indigenous_flag: No, Remoteness: Metro, ASSISTANCE: 2}]
```

Note: the query above can be used as a subquey, a cte, or made into a view. This is left to you and not included below, but it is assumed you have done the transform.

From the transformed data the counts and percentages can be calculated like this:

```
SELECT
  key,
  value,
  COUNT(*) as count,
  COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY key) as percentage
FROM
  Transformed_data
LATERAL VIEW explode(key_value_pairs) keyTable AS key, value
GROUP BY
  key, value
```

This should produce a result like this:

| key | value | count | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GENDER_TYP | Male | 1 | 20.0 |
| GENDER_TYP | Female | 2 | 40.0 |
| GENDER_TYP | Not stated | 2 | 40.0 |
| Employment_flag | Yes | 2 | 40.0 |
| Employment_flag | No | 3 | 60.0 |
| Indigenous_flag | No | 5 | 100.0 |
| Remoteness | Very remote | 1 | 20.0 |
| Remoteness | Metro | 2 | 40.0 |
| Remoteness | Rural | 1 | 20.0 |
| Remoteness | Remote | 1 | 20.0 |
| ASSISTANCE | 1 | 1 | 20.0 |
| ASSISTANCE | 2 | 2 | 40.0 |
| ASSISTANCE | 3 | 2 | 40.0 |

Some options for combining the 2 queries:

**using "derived table"** (subquery)

```
SELECT
     KEY
    , value
    , COUNT(*) AS count
    , COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY KEY) AS percentage
FROM (
        SELECT
              AGE_GROUP
            , map_entries(map('GENDER_TYP', GENDER_TYP, 'Employment_flag', Employment_flag, 'Indigenous_flag', Indigenous_flag, 'Remoteness', Remoteness, 'ASSISTANCE', ASSISTANCE)) AS key_value_pairs
        FROM source_table
        ) AS Transformed_data 
LATERAL VIEW explode(key_value_pairs) keyTable AS KEY , value
GROUP BY
     KEY
    , value
;
```

**using Common Table Expression** (CTE)

```
WITH transformed_data AS (
        SELECT AGE_GROUP
            , map_entries(map('GENDER_TYP', GENDER_TYP, 'Employment_flag', Employment_flag, 'Indigenous_flag', Indigenous_flag, 'Remoteness', Remoteness, 'ASSISTANCE', ASSISTANCE)) AS key_value_pairs
        FROM source_table
        )
SELECT
      KEY
    , value
    , COUNT(*) AS count
    , COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY KEY) AS percentage
FROM Transformed_data 
LATERAL VIEW explode(key_value_pairs) keyTable AS KEY, value
GROUP BY
      KEY
    , value
;
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm getting an error when running your code verbatim (after ncluding **create table transformed_data as** in the first code snippet). The error is:
AnalysisException: [UDTF_ALIAS_NUMBER_MISMATCH] The number of aliases supplied in the AS clause does not match the number of columns output by the UDTF. Expected 1 aliases, but got key,value. Please ensure that the number of aliases matches the number of columns output by the UDTF.

Comment: Also, the clause "lateral view" is black coloured font, it doesn't turn blue in my code (like it does with "group by" ).

Comment: You don't need to create a table (although that is an option) - I will add a combined approach to make it simpler. Databricks does support lateral views see: https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-lateral-view.html

Answer (score 0):

When you have lots of columns that you want to treat essentially the same, this might indicate you need a table redesign. SQL really doesn't like it when you want to use columns as a variable.

Right now you have one table that crams many different things together. For starters we have the survey itself which is made up of questions.

- Surveys
- Questions

  - Surveys have many questions

```
create table surveys (
  id serial primary key
);

create table questions (
  id serial primary key,
  question text not null
);

-- A survey has many questions
create table survey_questions (
  survey_id integer not null references surveys,
  question_id integer not null references questions,

  -- Each survey can only ask a question once.
  unique(survey_id, question_id)
);
```

Now we have a list of questions we can use, and we can store many surveys with different (possibly overlapping) questions in one database.

Next we have the responses to surveys, the respondents, and their answers to the questions. Each response has many answers.

- Respondents
- Responses to surveys

  - Surveys have many responses
- Answers

  - Survey responses have many answers

```
create table respondents (
  id serial primary key,
  name text not null
);

-- Stores information about this particular response to the survey, including meta information like
-- when the response happened, level of assistance, etc.
create table survey_responses (
  id serial primary key,

  survey_id integer not null references surveys,
  respondent_id integer not null references respondents,
  
  assistance integer not null,
  responded_at timestamp default current_timestamp,

  -- Each respondent can only take the survey once.
  unique(survey_id, respondent_id)
);

-- A survey response has many answers
create table survey_response_answers (
  survey_response_id integer not null references survey_responses,
  -- this could also reference survey_questions, not sure which is better
  question_id integer not null references questions,
  answer text not null,

  -- Each question can only be answered once per response.
  unique(survey_response_id, question_id)
);
```

Now that questions are their own entity, we can create a query to count by question, answer, and assistance. (Note: This will give you results for the questions which were answered. If you want all questions, even those with no answers, use `from survey_questions` and left join on survey_responses and survey_response_answers.)

```
select
  sra.question_id,
  sra.answer,
  sr.assistance,
  count(*) as Count
from survey_response_answers sra
join survey_responses sr on sra.survey_response_id = sr.id
where sr.survey_id = 1
group by 1, 2, 3
```

We can do a similar query grouped just by question and answer. (If you want all survey questions, not just ones which

```
  select
    question_id,
    answer,
    count(*) as count
  from survey_response_answers sra
  join survey_responses sr on sra.survey_response_id = sr.id
  where sr.survey_id = 1
  group by 1, 2
```

And join them together, plus the questions table to get the text of the question.

```
with totals as (
  select
    question_id,
    answer,
    count(*) as count
  from survey_response_answers sra
  join survey_responses sr on sra.survey_response_id = sr.id
  where sr.survey_id = 1
  group by 1, 2
),
subtotals as (
  select
    sra.question_id as question_id,
    sra.answer as answer,
    sr.assistance as assistance,
    count(*) as count
  from survey_response_answers sra
  join survey_responses sr on sra.survey_response_id = sr.id
  where sr.survey_id = 1
  group by 1, 2, 3
)
select
  q.question as Question,
  subtotals.answer as Answer,
  subtotals.assistance as Assistance,
  subtotals.count as Count,
  totals.count as Total,
  (100.0 * subtotals.count / totals.count) as Pct
from subtotals
join totals
  on subtotals.question_id = totals.question_id
 and subtotals.answer = totals.answer
join questions q
  on q.id = subtotals.question_id
order by 1, 2, 3
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/0gez0RrW) (in Postgres, which should be similar to Databricks).

You might not be able to do a redesign like this, but you can consider this for the future.